code -32007 and -32009
Quick question:
We've been getting this
"error":{"code":-32007,"message":"Slot 267558672 was skipped, or missing due to ledger jump to recent snapshot"}
and this one
error -32009 with the message "Slot XXX was skipped, or missing in long-term storage".
error lately, saying a slot was skipped or missing due to a ledger jump. When this happens, should we just skip that block and move on to the next one, or is there a possibility that transactions might be missed in the process?
Thanks for any help you can give!

Can you give more information about where you're seeing this error and what you're trying to do?

Hey, in our crypto exchange project, I'm syncing the blockchain locally. I fetch each block and its transactions, then match them with our users' wallet addresses. If there's a match, I create deposits. We're using the Solana testnet RPC endpoint (https://api.testnet.solana.com) and the getBlock method. However, we often encounter this above error instead of a new block. Even when checking on the Explorer network, the block isn't available. So, my main concern is whether we should skip that block or keep retrying to fetch it.

Ah great, it might simply be that the block doesn't exist because it got skipped, in which case, it's totally fine to skip it
